# Unknown CRC Method

Tags: hex, crc, modbus, octal, rs485

I having following modbus polling query but i am unable find the correct crc method,crc position and crc value please guide me to find correct crc method,crc position and crc value for the following query

```
01 37 37 1D 31 31 31 1D 30 1D 31 03 32 35 30 34 39 04
01 37 37 1D 31 31 31 1D 30 1D 32 03 32 35 30 34 33 04
01 37 37 1D 31 31 31 1D 30 1D 33 03 35 37 38 31 34 04
01 37 37 1D 31 31 31 1D 30 1D 34 03 32 35 30 33 31 04
01 37 37 1D 31 31 31 1D 30 1D 35 03 35 37 37 39 34 04
```

for the above modbus polling query i am not getting which one is crc value and what type of crc used. How it is came and 77 is id of the device. Please guide me..

I am getting following response from the device for polling

```
01 37 37 02 33 1D 30 39 33 31 39 30 39 34 38 32 30 30 37 31 31 42 20 30 30 30 
30 30 30 30 38 34 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 37 38 30 30 30 30 
30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 33 35 31 30 30 30 30 30 
30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 03 34 37 33 38 35 04
```

Comment: I am tried crc 32 crc16 but not find the correct method

Comment: There are no CRC bytes in those messages.

Comment: Then how to check the error in data

Comment: We need more information to be able to give an answer. You say that the slave ID is ‘77’. But this slave ID is not present in the data supplied. Modbus RTU uses CRC-16 appended as two bytes by the transmitter.

Comment: slave id is mentioned in modbus that is 01 37 37

Comment: what information you want

Answer (score 1):

First of all:

- The `MODBUS over Serial Line` standard is available [here](https://modbus.org/docs/Modbus_over_serial_line_V1_02.pdf). This completely specifies low-level interface to MODBUS.
- The `MODBUS Application Protocol Specification` is available [here](https://modbus.org/docs/Modbus_Application_Protocol_V1_1b3.pdf). Higher-level MODBUS commands are specified here.
- Both of these standards are fairly short, easy to read and understand, and contain nice diagrams, so I highly recommend you look at them for answers.

Your data doesn't appear to conform to these standards, which makes it hard to answer your questions!

The serial line standard describes two communication methods, RTU and ASCII, but only the RTU method uses a CRC. So you must be using the RTU communication method since you're asking about CRC.

Assuming the RTU communication method, then the slave address should be the first byte, and the function code should be the second byte. That would mean that the slave address is `01`, and the function code is `37`. But that's not right, because the Application Protocol Specification page 11 lists all the function codes, and `37` is not a valid function code. Also, the slave address `01` doesn't match the slave address 77 that you claim to be using.

But let's ignore that for the moment. Your specific questions are about CRC.

- The RTU communication method is the only one which uses a CRC. The ASCII communication method uses a Longitudinal Redundancy Check (LRC), which is different.
- The RTU communication method uses a CRC-16, meaning the CRC has 16 bits = 2 bytes. The details are contained in the serial line standard, and there is even some sample C code for computing the CRC there. There are also multiple implementations in various languages available if you google, but do be careful because there are several different CRC-16 definitions and you need to make sure that what you use matches the MODBUS standard.
- The CRC position in a MODBUS frame is at the very end of the frame. The last two bytes (16 bits) are the CRC. The low-order byte of the CRC is appended first, followed by the high-order byte.
- The MODBUS queries that you provide do NOT appear to have a CRC appended to them at all. But, as I mentioned earlier, the MODBUS queries that you provide don't even look like they use the RTU communication method, which is the only method that uses a CRC.

---

Since your data doesn't seem to follow the RTU communication method, perhaps it uses the ASCII communication method, which is described starting on page 16 of the serial line standard. The ASCII communication method always starts with an ASCII `:` character, which is `3A` in hex. The ASCII communication method always ends with ASCII cr and lf characters, which are `0D` and `0A` in hex. All other characters between these must be 0-9 or A-F characters, which are `30` through `39` and `41` through `46` in hex. Your message does not obey any of these requirements - it doesn't start with `3A`, it doesn't end with `0D` `0A`, and it contains other characters that are not `30` through `39` or `41` through `46`.

If we ignore that and assume that your data follows the ASCII communication method, then:

- The LRC field would be the last two bytes before the `0D` `0A` at the end.
- Page 18 of the serial line standard describes how LRC is computed. It is very simple:

```
The LRC is calculated by adding together successive 8–bit bytes of
the message, discarding any carries, and then two’s complementing the
result.  It is performed on the bytes of the message, before the
encoding of each byte in the two ASCII characters corresponding to the
hexadecimal representation of each nibble.  The computation does not include
the 'colon' character that begins the message, and does not include the CRLF
pair at the end of the message.  The resulting LRC is ASCII encoded into two
bytes and placed at the end of the ASCII mode frame before the CRLF.
```

- Page 38 of the serial line standard give example C code for generating the LRC. It is only 9 lines of code.

---

Your data does not follow either of the communication methods. We would need to know more about where your data came from to figure out what went wrong. Perhaps the data is somehow corrupted by multiple devices, or perhaps the sensor that measures the data has incorrect timing or voltage or something, causing it to mis-understand the values being sent. Perhaps there is some kind of parity mis-match, causing some bytes to be thrown away. But we just can't tell without more information.

Comment: Can we tried in LRC method i am not sure about this query

Comment: Your data doesn't look like the ASCII communication method either. That's the one that uses LRC. I'll add to my answer above.